# Increment/Decrement operation to make Greatest common divisor as K

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of size N.

Also, we are given operation where we can increment/decrement any element of array by 1.

Our Goal is to make GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of all elements equal to a given number K in minimum number of operations.

So, we need to find the minimum number of operations required.

**Example** :  Say N=3 and array is [4,5,6] and K=5 then here answer is 2.
We can have GCD as 5 by decreasing value of 6 in one operation and increasing value of 4 to 5 in second operation.

**My approach :** 
Our final goal is something like :

**[x1 * k,x2 * k,....x3 ∗ k], where gcd(x1,x2....xn)=1 (xi ∗ k is what we replace array element at its position with)**

Maintain states in separate array DP[i][j] , where DP[i][j] = minimum operations required to get gcd of [x1,x2...xi] equal to j.

The answer will be DP[N][1], where N is the size of the array.

But as this approach clearly depends on range of elements, and all elements can range upto 1000000. Also N, K can also go upto 1000000.

What can be better way to approach this problem. ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Homework type questions are okay, but please try to ask something a little more specific than "What can be better way to approach this problem?"

Comment: Are negative values allowed on input, or output?

Comment: @Airhead Sure. First time for me :) Thanks for advice

Comment: @STF Only non negative positive integers

Comment: There are special web pages for first-timers. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: so you want to find an array with gcd 1? your given array is already so i.e 0 operations needed. what are your next steps?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in hackerearth's some company hiring challenge.I was able to pass sample test case and some of my own testcases, but not any of online judge test case. here is my approach:

```
    def gcd(a,b):
    if b>a:
        a,b = b,a
    while b:
        a,b = b,a%b
    return a 
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    k,n = map(int,input().split())
    arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ops = 0
    n1 = arr[0]
    n2 = arr[1]
    g = gcd(n1,n2)
    if g!=k:
        i,j = n1%k,n2%k
        if i and j:
            ops = min(i,k-i)+min(j,k-j)
        else:
            if i:
                ops = min(k-i,i)
            elif j:
                 ops = min(k-j,j)
    for i in range(2,n):
        g = gcd(k,arr[i])
        if g!=k:
            j = arr[i]%k
            ops += min(k-j,j)
    print(ops)
```

Secondly my thought is just traverse the array and find out how many steps would it take to convert the arr[i]%k==0 and find minimum of that and add to answer which was basically my first approach too.

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    k,n = map(int,input().split())
    arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ops = 0

    for num in arr:
        rem = num%k
        if rem>0:
            ops+=min(rem,k-rem)
    print(ops)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code passed all the test cases for me in java

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = s.nextInt();
    while (t > 0) {
        int k = s.nextInt();
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            nums[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        long opt = 0;
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (num == k) {
                continue;
            }
            if (num < k) {
                opt += k - num;
            } else {
                int rem = num % k;
                if (rem > 0) {
                    opt += Math.min(rem, k - rem);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(opt));
        t--;
    }
```